# Can't make infinite scroll work in Firefox with overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none

Tags: jquery, firefox, infinite-scroll

I have UI layout, that i would not like to change (it's not mine, there's designer supplies us with it).
The requirement is to scroll tbody content with scrollbars turned off.
It works flawlessly in Chrome and IE and event is

```
$(global.table).find('tbody').on('scroll', function () { /*AJAX load next rows*/ });
```

However, Firefox is where I stucked. With overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none it does not want to scroll tbody content!

I've decided to use

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(document).innerHeight() >= $('body').get(0).scrollHeight) {
    global.showNextRows();
  }
});
```

And it works by manipulating scrollTop position of document, but tbody content is not scrolled - i can't see the appended rows. I know i can use ScrollIntoView or other stuff, but how to make this in a most natural way?

```
//Called by showNextRows
function InsertRows(data, status, xhr) {
  var rowHeight = global.getRows().first().height();
  $(data).insertAfter(global.getRows().filter(':last'));
  var takenRows = $(data).filter('tr').length;
  if (takenRows < global.requestedTake) {
    //$(global.table).find('tbody').off('scroll');
    $(document).off('scroll');
  } else {
    $(document).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - takenRows * rowHeight);
  }
  Success(data, status, xhr);
}
```

Comment: `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none` is [deprecated and should be replaced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) by `overflow: hidden`, have you tried this?

Comment: I cannot use overflow: hidden, because then scroll event does not get fired in Chrome for tbody. Anyway, it does not resolve the current problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following dirty hack :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i)) {
      $(global.container).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
      $(global.container).css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
      $(global.table).find('tbody').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
      $(global.table).find('tbody').css('padding-right', '16px');
  }
  ...
}
```